# Multiple model authentication in Rails using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have a User model and an admin model and I am using devise for authentication. My Admin logins using an email and password. My User can login using both email and username. What should my

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.authentication_keys = [ : ]
```

line should be and do I need to override devise to achieve this ?

Comment: Check out the wiki on devise, there is an article with this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is email a required field for the User?  If so, you can overwrite the Devise SessionController locate the user's email if username is used and process the authentication.

I would also STRONGLY advise against having a separate User and Admin model, unless Admin inherits User.  You are only asking for problems in user management.  I would recommend setting a role[s] attribute on the User model and using a framework like [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) to manage access policy.

Comment: Thanks. But why is it not advisable to use different models ?

Comment: Other than you are going to have 2 DB tables that are almost identical, what if you have an existing User that you want to make an Admin, or Admin you want to demote to a User?  Furthermore, if you make any high level changes to Devise, you will have to rely those changes in multiple places.

Comment: What if there isn't any association between User and Admin ? And I'm planning to have many attributes to User which are not needed for Admin. Isn't it simple to have different tables ?